# Google API route created from origin:latitude/longitude and destination:placeId doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I've followed google documentation and ended up with this:

```
function nearbySearchCallback(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var place = results[i];

        createInfoWindow(place.name, place.geometry.location);
        //calculateAndDisplayRoute(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng());
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(place);
        break;
    }
}
else if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
    //alert("No matching places");
}
else{
    alert("Error!");
}
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(destObj) {
console.log("id " + destObj.id);
var selectedMode = "Driving";//document.getElementById('mode').value;
console.log("start point: " + locationX + ", " + locationY);
directionsService.route({
    origin: {lat: locationX, lng: locationX},  
    destination: {placeId: destObj.id},
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
}, 
function(response, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
});
}
```

The response is: Directions request failed due to NOT_FOUND

Why is this happening?
locationX and locationY are lat/lng from gps and i am pretty sure that the destObj is a shop near my location. So why google says it can't find any routes?

If I change origin/destination to arbitrary locations from googles docs:

```
origin: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447},  // Haight.
destination: {lat: 37.768, lng: -122.511},  // Ocean Beach.
```

then it starts to work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code `.id` is not the `placeId` in the place object.  According to [the documentation for PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlaceResult), that is `.place_id`.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gz657tjf/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 500,
    type: ['store']
  }, nearbySearchCallback);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function nearbySearchCallback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results.length);
    var place = results[3];
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(place);
  } else if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
    //alert("No matching places");
  } else {
    alert("Error!");
  }
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(destObj) {
  console.log("id " + destObj.place_id);
  var selectedMode = "Driving";
  directionsService.route({
      origin: {
        lat: map.getCenter().lat(),
        lng: map.getCenter().lng()
      },
      destination: {
        placeId: destObj.place_id
      },
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    },
    function(response, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```